# strikethrough label in HTML

Tags: strikethrough

i can't strike the label in HTML. I tried strike,s,del. But they don't work.

The code :

```
<div id="durunfiyatl2"><label><s><?php echo($_SESSION['indirimsizfiyaty']); ?> €</s></label></div>

  <p><strike>ADANA</strike></p>
```

How can i resolve this problem?

I need your help.

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: @HassanImam thanks. It work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> Try using css
.strike{
text-decoration: line-through;
}
<span class="strike">ADANA</span>
```